# Add colour overlay to non transparent part of a PNG

Tags: php, laravel, image

I am trying to accomplish having a colour wheel and it will add an overlay to a PNG image with a 50% opacity so you can still see the outlines of the image behind.

I have tried using intervention fill methods and changing it on a per-pixel basis.

```php
private function colorImage($url, $r = null, $g = null, $b = null) {

        $im = imagecreatefrompng($url);
        imageAlphaBlending($im, true);
        imageSaveAlpha($im, true);

        if (imageistruecolor($im)) {
            $sx = imagesx($im);
            $sy = imagesy($im);
            for ($x = 0; $x < $sx; $x++) {
                for ($y = 0; $y < $sy; $y++) {
                    $c = imagecolorat($im, $x, $y);
                    $a = $c & 0xFF000000;
                    $newColor = $a | $r << 16 | $g << 8 | $b;
                    imagesetpixel($im, $x, $y, $newColor);
                }
            }
        }

        ob_start();

        imagepng($im);
        imagedestroy($im);
        $image_data = ob_get_contents();

        ob_end_clean();

        $image_data_base64 = "data:image/png;base64," . base64_encode($image_data);

        return $image_data_base64;
}
```

Before: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgeiQ.jpg

Current: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQxmM.jpg

Objective: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5JQW.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Intervention Image](http://image.intervention.io/) image library to do this.

Create an instance that is an image filled with your semi-transparent RGB color, mask it off using the source image, and lay the mask on top of the original as an overlay.

```
use Intervention\Image\ImageManager;

// setup
$red     = 255;
$green   = 0;
$blue    = 0;
$opacity = 0.25;

$manager = new ImageManager(['driver' => 'gd']);

// the source image
$image = $manager->make('./board.png');

// the fill color
$fill = $manager->canvas(
    $image->width(), 
    $image->height(), 
    [$red, $green, $blue, $opacity]
);

// use the source image to mask off only the portion of the fill that will be 
// used as the overlay
$fill->mask($image, true);

// apply the semi-transparent, masked fill to the source image
$image->insert($fill);

// render as a png
header('Content-Type: image/png');
echo $image->encode('png');
```

**Output:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGLyD.jpg